# Match pseudo random numbers between MT19937 CPU and GPU

Tags: c++, cuda

I am studying the behaviour of `CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_MT19937`, specifically in order to match numbers generated by the standard CPU implemetation of Mersenne Twister (`std::mt19937` or `boost::random::mt19937`).

I read in the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.1.0/curand/host-api-overview.html#order) that cuRand MT19937 “has the same parameters as CPU version, but ordering is different […] Output is generated by 8192 independent generators. Each generator generates consecutive subsequence of the original sequence. […] Results are permuted differently than originally to achieve higher performance.”

Checking the unsigned int output sequences of `std::mt19937` and cuRand MT19937 with the same seed, only the first number is equal and immediately the two generators diverge.

Consider that in my CPU environment, I have a distributed computation that instantiate `n` `std::mt19937` with incremental seeds (`s+1`, `s+2`, etc.). Do you know if there is a way to modify the cuRand MT19937 generators in order to match my workflow?

Thanks

Comment: If the GPU version has 8192 independent generators, I would assume the value in index 8192 corresponds to the second CPU value. Have you checked this?

Comment: If the individual generators produce sub-sequences of length 2^1000, I assume you can in theory create the second generator by advancing the first by that amount. I don't see how you could do this with the API presented by the ```std::random```. Maybe a different random number library can

Comment: Yes, this is my understaing as well. There are 8192 generators, each of them with the state advanced respectively by 2^1000 numbers than the previous. Then the output is generated by eights but the order is somehow permuted to achieve better performance. My question is about finding a way to modify the cuRand MT19937 in order to have multiple generators initialized with different seeds.

Comment: I do not think you can modify your implementation of CuRand but you can modify the CPU version. The main thing is that a sequential program can easily mimic a parallel one but a parallel program cannot mimic a sequential program efficiently.